# .post call not returning expected response

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I am building out the backend for a flash card app for which you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/jevoncochran/flashr-server). There is a table called `categories`. There is an endpoint for adding a category.

```
router.post("/", protect, createCategory);
```

The endpoint runs a `createCategory` function which has logic separated out into a `categoryController.js` file.

```
const Categories = require("../models/categoryModel");

const createCategory = async (req, res) => {
  const { title } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user.id;

  if (!title) {
    res.status(404).json({ errMsg: "Please provide a title" });
  } else {
    const category = await Categories.createCategory({ title, userId });
    console.log("category: ", category);
    res.status(201).json(category);
  }
};
```

The createCategory controller function in turn calls a createCategory function from the categoryModel.js file. The function from the model runs the database operations. Specifically, it inserts a new category into the database and references another function--getCategoryById--to return the newly created category.

```
const getCategoryById = (id) => {
  return db("categories").where({ id }).first();
};

const createCategory = (category) => {
  return db("categories")
    .insert(category, "id")
    .then((ids) => {
      const [id] = ids;
      return getCategoryById(id);
    });
};
```

The problem is when I make the .post to create a new category, nothing is returned in the response. The database gets updated just fine but nothing is returned. You can see that I put a console.log in the controller and that is coming back `undefined`. I am not sure why.

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like, `Categories.createCategory` and `getCategoryById` are not being awaited correctly. Does `db("categories")` return a promise? If not, then you might need to add async and await within those two functions, so that they are awaited correctly. Have you tried adding a `console.log` within `Categories.createCategory` and `getCategoryById` to see how the flow really is?

Comment: what about using async/await in `createCategory` function?